# My node-inspector console is malfunctioning

Tags: express, nodemon, node-inspector

I am currently learning express and are now trying to debug my app so that I can get hold of variables and objects within it. 
But when I type anything into the console when a breakpoint has been hit the console just ignores what I've typed and jumps down a line.

**This is a gif illustrating my problem:**
https://i.gyazo.com/4bd1d13f4ae666895c20fa3d2cdf9925.gif

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some update to Chrome(dev-tools) has resulted in a change in eventType which resulted in issue in [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector)

Following issues have been reported:

1. https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/903
2. https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/937

Probable fix which hasn't been merged yet: 
https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/pull/942